# PHP PDO Connection to Azure SQL - Invalid Object Name [table]

Tags: php, sql-server, azure, pdo

A client has set up an SQL database on the Azure cloud. I am trying to use PDO to connect, but as soon as I try to access a table's data, I get an error message.

My code to connect:

```
try {
    $db = new PDO('sqlsrv:server=tcp:serverid.database.windows.net,1433;Database=testdb','user','pass');
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Error " . $e->getMessage();      
}
```

This works fine and produces no errors. My code to insert...

```
try {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tablename (introduction) VALUES (:introduction)";
    $q = $db->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array(':introduction'=>'hi'));    
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Error " . $e->getMessage();      
}
```

I get the following error from that

```
Error SQLSTATE[42S02]: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'tablename'.
```

Tablename is definitely a table which does exist. We have checked permissions and don't believe it's that. I am stuck. PDO is new to me so I don't know if there's something obvious I've missed??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting the tablename in this format:

```
dbname.tablename
```

Not the best solution but it did work for me.

Comment: thanks! I tried with database.dbo.tablename but had the same error message. Trying without the dbo worked fine though. I have other errors, but they are relating to inserting NULLs so I assume it's working now! thank you :)

Comment: I guess it was dbo just in my case. You're welcome :)

Comment: Thanks! What's annoying is I did try dbname.dbo.table before and never tried it without the dbo!! Can't believe it was that simple.....!! cheers :)

Comment: Hi @Dan see my previous edit on the answer. I gave the exact same thing which you recommended but it wasn't working for him. Maybe its some schema related issue?!

Comment: I would normally put `$db->exec("USE database");` but I believe that doesn't work with Auzure SQL?

Comment: I'm not even familiar with Auzure lol. I faced a similar problem in SQL Server few days back so I thought this might help you too since they both are from Microsoft and Azure is kind of a subset of SQL server.