# Show column of table in PHP with SQL database

Tags: php, sql-server

Hi i need to show the column 'Titel' from table 'Algemeen' im working with `Microsoft SQL Server Management`

This is the code where i am trying it

```
<?php
try
{
    //connectie met sql-server
    $pdo = new PDO('sqlsrv:server=JARI\SQLEXPRESSSCHOOL;database=ijdb;','','');
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    die ('Unable to connect to the database server.' . $e->getMessage());
}
$sql = 'SELECT Titel FROM Algemeen ORDER BY Titel';
    foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
        print $row['Titel'] . "\n";}
?>
```

And this is the error message i am getting

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'Algemeen'.' in D:\ICT Opleiding\Applicatieontwikkeling\EmptySite28\PHPPage.php:13
Stack trace:
#0 D:\ICT Opleiding\Applicatieontwikkeling\EmptySite28\PHPPage.php(13): PDO->query('SELECT Titel FR...')
#1 {main}
  thrown in D:\ICT Opleiding\Applicatieontwikkeling\EmptySite28\PHPPage.php on line 13
```

Comment: Could you try with `FROM databasename.schemaname.Algemeen ORDER BY Titel`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the answer provided in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30332981/php-pdo-connection-to-azure-sql-invalid-object-name-table).

Which indicates that you may need to add the database name to your query so it would look more like (assuming ijdb is your database name)

```
$sql = 'SELECT Titel FROM ijdb.Algemeen ORDER BY Titel';
```